# using pandas dataframe extract special character(:) from one column and fill same row value till next character occurs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas dataframe a I want to extract special character text from one column & `ffill` (forward fill) to fill the same values up to the next occurrence of the special character, deleting the special character rows after extraction. I have tried the following but am not getting my desired result.

Input dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['White color :', 'I am not really sure how to do this', 'I am not really sure how to do this', 
             'Black color :', 'I am not ready to solve your issue',
           'I am not ready to solve your issue','I am not ready to solve your issue'],
    
     })

df['new_col'] = df['col1'].str.extract('^([^:]+)', expand=False)
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(':')).any(axis=1)
df.loc[mask, :] = df.loc[mask, :].ffill(axis=1)
df
```

Desired output dataframe

```
    col1                                       new_col   
 0  I am not really sure how to do this        White color
 1  I am not really sure how to do this        White color
 2  I am not ready to solve your issue         Black color 
 3  I am not ready to solve your issue         Black color 
 4  I am not ready to solve your issue         Black color
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your approach :

```
m = df["col1"].str.contains(":", na=False)

out = (df.assign(new_col=df["col1"].str.extract(r"^([^:]+)", expand=False)
                 .where(m).ffill()).loc[~m]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                                  col1       new_col
0  I am not really sure how to do this  White color 
1  I am not really sure how to do this  White color 
2   I am not ready to solve your issue  Black color 
3   I am not ready to solve your issue  Black color 
4   I am not ready to solve your issue  Black color
```

Comment: Your code gives : `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: Do you test it before the *copy/paste* ? It still throw the same error.

Comment: Yeah let me check once again

Comment: You gave this time a valid *DataFrame* constructor but what's the problem ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get you. Either add the new input/expected output to your question above or open a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of buteforce but it works like a charm.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['White color :', 'I am not really sure how to do this', 'I am not really sure how to do this', 
             'Black color :', 'I am not ready to solve your issue',
           'I am not ready to solve your issue','I am not ready to solve your issue'],
    
     })

special_character_set = ["White color :", "Black color :"]
special_char = ""
special = []
temp = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["col1"] in special_character_set:
        special_char = row["col1"][:-2]
    else:
        temp.append(row["col1"])
        special.append(special_char)    

final_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1" : temp,
    "new_col": special
})
```